# Mayavi integration in PyQt6 application

Tags: pyqt6, mayavi

I am trying to integrate Mayavi with qframe in pyqt6 application, but not able to. Anyone with a simple example code that can do that will be appreciated. Thanks

```py
import mayavi
import PyQt6

class MainWindow(PyQt6.QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mayavi_scene = mayavi.mlab.new_scene()

        # Add the Mayavi scene to the PyQt6 window.
        self.mayavi_widget = mayavi.mlab.embed_in_qt5(self.mayavi_scene, parent=self)

        # Display the PyQt6 window.
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = PyQt6.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't know what that `embed_in_qt` function does (as far as I could search, it doesn't exist in mayavi), but if it does return a Qt widget, you need to add it to the window using an appropriate [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (such as QVBoxLayout), as just creating it may not be sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a simple example code that can do what I am looking for? (embeding mayavi scene/plot in qt6 frame). Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't use mayavi. Do some research on layout management in Qt, starting from these tutorials: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials